# Ownership of objects stored in a vector

Tags: c++, memory-management

I'm tring to learn C++ and I have a little problem. I have some instances of Foo class. And I have a FooContainer with `vector<Foo> data` with a method

```
void FooContainer::add(Foo item) {
    this->data.push_back(item)
}
```

I want FooContainer to be the real holder of Foo elements. I don't understand what is the better way to pass the items from main to Foo.

In my main I have:

```
Foo item(...);
container.add(item);
```

In this way I have an object allocated in main, and I pass a copy to the container. I have the element existing in 2 place, so I have to delete the one in the main after all `add()`.

Or is better to have a pointer in the main, construct the item with `new` keyword, and pass the pointer? And in this way Container.data should be a `vector<Foo*>`?

Or, again, have the element in main, add in the container by reference, and not delete it in main?

I'm a bit confused.

#### EDIT

for educational purpose i don't want to use c++11 or boost shared pointer: my ideas are confused on pointer and reference and basic things, before pass into advanced argument (even if more elegant) i want to have clear basis of what i am doing!

Comment: Passing a pointer like `container.add(new Foo(...));` would work fine providing you changed you method prototype and vector.

Comment: ... but it would be a bad idea.

Comment: @nkint: What's in `Foo`?

Comment: inside foo there are 3 matrixes, 1 method that freturn void but changes that matrixes, and 1 method that give the determinant

Comment: looking at amit answer, yes i have also DerivedFoo

Comment: @Chad: as long as you add all the necessary logic to make sure it's not leaked when it's removed from the container.

Comment: @Mike: and for bonus points, make sure it's not leaked when `push_back` throws :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It all depends on your need.

If all your instances are `Foo` [and not a subclass of `Foo`], IMO using `vector<Foo>` is simpler and thus should be preferred.

However, if you have a class `Bar` which extends `Foo`, trying to add it to your `vector` will cause [object slicing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing), and your program will behave not as expected. In this case, you should prefer `vector<Foo*>`

So, as I started - it all depends on the specific need, but the last point must be considered if you plan on extending `Foo`.

Comment: ok so i should prefer a vector of pointer but in this case.. where are my data? where should i have to delete? only in FooContainer deconstructor?

Comment: Except that: in this case, you should prefer `boost::ptr_vector<Foo>` or `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Foo>>`.

Comment: @nkint: Yes, in the destructor of `FooContainer`, and upon removal - if `FooContainer` supports it.

Comment: @SteveJessop Or not.  Polymorphic objects are generally entity objects, and I don't think I've ever encountered a case where a container should be responsible for deleting an entity object.  It's just not their role.  (With regards to `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Foo>>`: something like `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Foo>> p = v[0];` is going to effectively remove the object from the container.  I don't think I like this.

Comment: @James: hmm, I think your treatment of entity objects, and your use of dynamic polymorphism exclusively for that purpose, may not hold for everyone's coding/design style, or even in the main. Someone took the time to write `boost::ptr_vector`, I guess they wouldn't be welcome on your team but they are on others ;-) The question says, "I want FooContainer to be the real holder of Foo elements", I interpret this to mean that it's going to take a lot of unpicking the existing design to move away from the container having ownership responsibilities.

Comment: For `unique_ptr`: sometimes a `vector<shared_ptr<Foo>>` would be better, it does depend what you're going to do with the pointers in the vector. If the vector is a replacement for what you initially thought could be a `vector<Foo>` then you wouldn't write `unique_ptr<Foo> p = v[0];`, rather `Foo f = *v[0]` or just directly use `v[0]`. Generic code might need some checking, make sure it copes with the fact that you've switched from a vector of the values you want, to a vector of indirections.

Comment: I've got nothing in general against using a `vector<Foo*>` where the container *doesn't* own the objects, it's just that in this question it certainly does, so `vector<Foo*>` leaves a bunch of work undone. The remaining choice is whether to use existing tools to do that work, or write a `delete` loop. The option "assume that someone else is responsible for ownership of entity objects" has IMO already been ruled out.

Comment: @SteveJessop Just because something's in `boost` doesn't mean that it's a good idea:-).  But while there are cases where it makes sense for the container to hold objects (and where polymorphism is useful on non-entity objects), but it's certainly not the most frequent case.  In this case, I think that the solution is probably `std::vector<Foo>`; once he's mastered that (and the C++ object model in general, with value semantics), then if he needs polymorphism, a `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Foo>>` might be appropriate.  But it's something to learn after you've learned value semantics.

Answer (score 2):

You could pass a temporary into the container; this will be destroyed at the end of the line:

```
container.add(Foo(...));
```

In C++11, you can construct it directly into the container:

```
template <typename Args...>
void FooContainer::emplace(Args && a) {
    data.emplace_back(std::forward(a));
}

container.emplace(...);
```

(My syntax might not be quite correct, as I haven't used variadic templates much)

In both these cases, remember that the container stores objects of type `Foo`. You can't store objects of subtypes; if you try, the objects will be "sliced" by only copying the base class part. If you need to store subtypes (as one of your comments implies you might), then you would have to store pointers.

> Or is better to have a pointer in the main, construct the item with new keyword, and pass the pointer?

That would create the complication of remembering to delete the object when removing it from the container. You could use `vector<unique_ptr<Foo>>` in C++11, or `boost::ptr_vector<Foo>` in C++03, to take care of that. This has the advantage that you could also store objects of subtypes of `Foo` in the container, if that's something you might want to do.

> Or, again, have the element in main, add in the container by reference, and not delete it in main?

You can't put references in containers. You could put pointers to local variables in the container, if very careful that they don't get destroyed while still in use (which is simple enough, if everything is scoped inside `main`). Again, this allows you to store subtypes of `Foo`, not just `Foo` itself.

Comment: OP stated he also has derived objects (presumably that go in the array).  Answer needs an update.

Comment: @nkint: it doesn't have to be like that. C++11 is the current version of C++, it's just that compilers haven't caught up yet. Unless you need to write C++03 code for some specific reason (like, you're working on an existing product that's compiled for release in C++03 mode and/or shipped as source to people using C++03 compilers), you might as well learn C++11 now and just bear in mind that some features won't be available everywhere yet. While learning, use whatever features your implementation supports.

Answer (score 2):

I find that boost::ptr_vector works really well for explicit ownership semantics.

I use it like this (note that I use VC9 hence I use `std::auto_ptr` instead of the improved `std::unique_ptr`):

```
//use unique_ptr instead if they are supported on your compiler
std::auto_ptr<MyClass> a( new MyClass("a") );
boost::ptr_vector<MyClass> owning_vector;
owning_vector.push_back(a);
// auto_ptr a is now invalid and the ownership of the object is 
// solely with owning_vector
```

So it would solve your issue of creating 2 objects, and it would also be clear about who owns the new'ed object.
Also in terms of semantics the pointer container family of APIs from boost have a more natural sytax than a vector of raw pointers (IMO).

Comment: I understand what you are saying as he did say "I want FooContainer to be the real holder of Foo elements". However I took that to mean he wanted the vector to `own` the object, which is what a ptr_vector would do for him.

Comment: comments removed: OP implied vector should also store derived classes.  I'd give you a +1 if you also mentioned `std::unique_ptr` which is now standard and works fine with vectors.

Comment: I'm stuck on VC9 for the time being.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not a matter of ownership as much as a matter of just overhead.

If you have a `vector<foo>` than each time you add an object to the vector it copies the value to the vector.
So besides creating the temporary object to add to the vector, and then delete, you are creating another object in the vector, an copying the value there.

So it would be best to just create a `vector<foo*>` to hold the objects.

Or better yet use a `shared_ptr<foo>` and `vector<shared_ptr<foo>>`

Comment: If he comes from a Java/C# background, it's easy to see where the ownership train of thought comes from though.